# Changing the units of integration bounds gives an incorrect answer

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am integrating the following integral over the length of a rod. The rod is 180 millimeters long which gives this integral.
$$\int_0^{180 \text{ mm}} (450+2.5x)(a_1x+a_2x^2) \, \mathrm{d}x.$$
This integral evaluates to $1530900000a_2+12150000a_1$. However, if I convert the length of the rod from millimeters to meters and evaluate the integral, the answer is no longer correct.

$$\int_0^{0.180 \text{ m}}(450+2.5x)(a_1x+a_2x^2) \, \mathrm{d}x = 7.295a_1+0.875a_2.$$
What am part of my process is incorrect? I was expecting to obtain the same coefficients on $a_1$ and $a_2$ divided by 1000.

Comment: You have to adjust the units of the constants (  the $450$ and the $2.5$) as well.

Comment: In particular, what are the units on $x$ that gave you the formula? Then what are the units on $450$, $2.5$, $a_1$, and $a_2$ that give a meaningful answer?

Comment: The units of 450 and 2.5x are N/mm. Evaluating the integral should give a value for work which has units of N*m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the $x$ in your first integral is being measured in millimeters, then so too is the $x$ in your second integral.  While you have changed the labeling of the units in the second integral, the fact is that are *actually* integrating over a rod of length $0.18$ mm (not $0.18$ m).

If you want to change the units to meters, then you need to perform a change of variables (or a "$u$-substitution"), and work with meters throughout.  In this case, change to a new variable $y$, which is measured in meters:
$$1000 y \text{ m} = x \text{ mm}. $$
Suppressing the units, this implies that
$$ \mathrm{d}y = \frac{1}{1000} \mathrm{d}x, $$
and that the limits of integration are
$$ x = 0 \implies y = 0,
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
x = 180 \implies y = \frac{180}{1000} = 0.18. $$
Thus
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{180} (450+2.5x)(a_1x+a_2x^2) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&\qquad= \int_0^{0.18} \left(450+2.5(1000y)\right)\left(a_1(1000y)+a_2(1000y)^2\right) \, \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1000}.
\end{align}
From here, the integration should be straightforward.